# raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension") ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

Tags: python, arrays

Heun is where I update the x and y values. I'm getting the 
" raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension "
error. I know there's a problem with my arrays and have tried messing with the length of each by sticking an arbitrary value at the front of each by putting a 1 in the square brackets for xposition, and for yposition, at the same time then run, then each one and run, but I still don't know what the error is trying to tell me or how to fix it. I had it print xposition and yposition for small iterations (20) but they both had a length of 20. I also tried to get it to print xposition.shape[0] and yposition.shape[0] but it said they didnt have shape attributes even though the error was saying that the problem was that  x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Tyler/Documents/Computational Physics/proj8.py", line 117, in <module>
    planet()
  File "C:/Users/Tyler/Documents/Computational Physics/proj8.py", line 115, in planet
    orbs = orbitx(r0,v0,Nstep,dt)
  File "C:/Users/Tyler/Documents/Computational Physics/proj8.py", line 101, in orbitx
    axarr[1,0].plot(times,Energy,times,kinetic,times,potential)
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1373, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 313, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining[:isplit], kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 282, in _plot_args
    x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 223, in _xy_from_xy
    raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

```
times = []
xposition=[]
yposition=[] 
xvelocity=[]
yvelocity=[]
ang_mom=[]
r_polar = []
theta_polar = []
kinetic = []
potential = []
E = []
#main loop to call Heun over and over again.  
for i in range(Nstep):   

    x,y,vx,vy = Heun(dt,x,y,vx,vy)  #note here is where do the Heun step        
    radius = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)       # you will need this quantity for a few things
    velocity = np.sqrt(vx**2 + vy**2) # you will need the magnitude of v for kinetic energy

    time += dt         #update time
    times.append(time) #store time       

    L = np.cross([x,y,0],[vx,vy,0])

    U = GM / radius

    KE = .5 * velocity**2 

    Energy = KE + U
    #the following keeps track of rmax and rmin
    if radius < r_min:
        r_min = radius
    elif radius > r_max:
        r_max = radius

    #now we store the information
    xposition.append(x)
    yposition.append(y)
    xvelocity.append(vx)
    yvelocity.append(vy)
    r_polar.append(radius)               #keeps track of r for plotting in polar coordinates
    theta_polar.append(math.atan2(y,x))  #keeps track of theta for polar coordinates
    kinetic.append(KE)
    potential.append(U)
    ang_mom.append(L)
    E.append(Energy)    
print xposition
print yposition
###create an array of the total energy at each step#####
#some plotting examples.  You do not need to do the plots like this
fig1,axarr = py.subplots(2,2)
axarr[0,0].plot(xposition,yposition)
axarr[0,0].set_title('two body orbit')
axarr[1,0].plot(times,Energy,times,kinetic,times,potential)
axarr[1,0].legend(['Total E','Kinetic', 'Potential'],loc=7)
axarr[1,0].set_title('Energy vs Time')
axarr[1,1].set_title('x position vs time')
py.subplot(222,polar=True)
py.plot(theta_polar,r_polar)
axarr[1,1].plot(times,xposition)
```

Comment: Post full traceback.

Comment: I think it's telling me the arrays x and y are different lengths but I don't know how to fix this

Comment: What do you mean traceback?

Comment: The full error you're receiving, not just the last line.

Comment: I had it print xposition and yposition for small iterations (20) but they both had a length of 20. I also tried to get it to print xposition.shape[0] and yposition.shape[0] but it said they didnt have shape attributes even though the error was saying that the problem was that  x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]

Comment: The error seems to rise in this line `axarr[1,0].plot(times,Energy,times,kinetic,times,potential)` from trying to plot using `matplotlib`. I can't run your code so I'm not sure the exact details

Comment: Yeah thats where it's saying the error is but then it says my x and y arrays have different lengths

Comment: It's a generic error, it means the x-axis and y-axis. So you can't plot 20 points for x-axis and 19 for y-axis. The problem is in your `times,Energy,kinetic,potential` variables.

Answer (score 0):

In my line:

axarr[1,0].plot(times,Energy,times,kinetic,times,potential)

I was trying to plot Energy but it was E that was my array because it was:

E = []

and,

Energy = KE + U

and,

E.append(Energy)

I just had to change the line to:
axarr[1,0].plot(times,E,times,kinetic,times,potential)